# stdout of a process to a file in python

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am working on the integration of two different processes into a single process, 
but i required to print the stdout of each process separately into two different files.
(possibly to a tkinter gui).

say process1 to file1 and process2 to file2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more information what do you have ? Are the two processes already running ? Or is your script going to run this two processes ?

Comment: what exactly is a "tkinter file"?

Comment: @deimus: my script will run the two process simultaneously.

Comment: @mgilson : i mean output in tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Python's subprocess will do this just fine ...

```
with open('process1.stdout', 'wb') as f1:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['process1'], stdout=f1)
with open('process2.stdout', 'wb') as f2:
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['process2'], stdout=f2)
```

Comment: you could close the files immediately after corresponding `Popen` calls.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Can you?  The process executes asynchronously, so what happens if the process writes more data after the file handle has been closed?  (I've never tried it).  Of course, if you're right, then I _ought_ to be using a context manager instead ...

Comment: file descriptors in the child process are not your concern but there is no point to keep the files open in the *parent*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- I'll take your word for it ;-)

Comment: now you could create a for-loop: `for cmd, filename in []:`. btw, don't take my word for it. It leads to cargo cult programming. If it is not clear from the docs then the docs should be fixed or it is not true in the first place.

Comment: @mgilson: is it possble to get the stdout into a tkinter screen??